# Random number out of three number in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

Hi I wanna get random numbers out of 2,3,5 . So i use this code.

```
function Random(low, hi) {
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (hi - low + 1) + low);
 }
```

But this is only for 2 numbers , But i wanna get for 1 time for example 3 for 2 time 5, and 3 time 3 , but of course not exactly in that order . Any ideas ?

Comment: put `2, 3, 5` into *array*; generate *random index* of the array; return item by the index

Comment: place the 2,3,5 as array elements and generate the index at random using your random function with 0 as low and 2 as high.

Comment: Use an array like: `[2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5]` and pick a random index.

Comment: Yeah i'll try this .

Comment: const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const shuffledArray = array.sort((a, b) => 0.5 - Math.random());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function random(numbers) {
     return numbers[Math.floor(Math.random()*numbers.length)];
}
```

Then you can call it with a list:

```
random([2, 3, 5])
```